# Print all the values in the combobox

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I can't get all the values from the values

```cs
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xml);
XmlNodeList values = doc.GetElementsByTagName("value");

string NameEx = "Properties.Name";

for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    if (values[i].InnerText == NameEx)
    {
        comboBox1.Text = values[i + 1].InnerText;
        i++;
    }
}
```

It prints me only the last node.(Text1)

I want to print in the comboBox1 both Image1 and Text1.

This is my XML:

```xml
<properties name="prop">
    <property>
        <type>0</type>
        <dataType>0</dataType>
        <key>key</key>
        <value>Properties.Name</value>
        <readOnly>0</readOnly>
    </property>
    <property>
        <type>0</type>
        <dataType>0</dataType>
        <key>value</key>
        <value>Image1</value>
        <readOnly>0</readOnly>
    </property>
</properties>
    <properties name="prop">
        <property>
            <type>0</type>
            <dataType>0</dataType>
            <key>key</key>
            <value>Properties.Name</value>
            <readOnly>0</readOnly>
        </property>
        <property>
            <type>0</type>
            <dataType>0</dataType>
            <key>value</key>
            <value>Text1</value>
            <readOnly>0</readOnly>
        </property>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add item in drop down list you have to use item.add() Property  as below

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xml);
XmlNodeList values = doc.GetElementsByTagName("value");

string NameEx = "Properties.Name";

for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
 if (values[i].InnerText == NameEx)
 {
    comboBox1.Items.Add(values[i + 1].InnerText);
    i++;
 }
}
```

if you want to add as Display Text then it should be like

```
doc.Load(xml);
XmlNodeList values = doc.GetElementsByTagName("value");

string NameEx = "Properties.Name";

for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    if (values[i].InnerText == NameEx)
    {
        comboBox1.text += (values[i + 1].InnerText);
        i++;
    }
}
```